# C++: How do I pass a function(without knowing its parameters) to another function?

Tags: c++, pointers, timer, function-pointers, parameter-passing

I'm trying to create a function that will store and repeat another function given as a parameter for a specific amount of time or repeats given.
But when you want to pass a function as a parameter you have to know all of its parameters before hand.
How would I do if I wanted to pass the function as one parameter, and the parameters as another?

```
void AddTimer(float time, int repeats, void (*func), params); // I know params has no type and that (*func) is missing parameters but it is just to show you what I mean
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dribeas' answer is correct as far as modern C++ is concerned.

For the sake of interest, there's also a simple lo-tech solution from the C world that as far as it goes, works in C++. Instead of allowing arbitrary parameters, define the function as `void (*func)(void*)`, and make "params" `void*`. It's then the caller's job to define some struct that will contain the parameters, and manage its lifecycle. Usually the caller would also write a simple wrapper to the function that's really needed to be called:

```
void myfunc(int, float); // defined elsewhere

typedef struct {
    int foo;
    float bar;
} myfunc_params;

void myfunc_wrapper(void *p) {
    myfunc_params *params = (myfunc_params *)p;
    myfunc(params->foo, params->bar);
}

int main() {
    myfunc_params x = {1, 2};
    AddTimer(23, 5, myfunc_wrapper, &x);
    sleep(23*5 + 1);
}
```

In practice you want to "fire and forget" timers, so if you use this scheme you may also need a way for the timer manage to free the userdata pointer once all firings have completed.

Obviously this has limited type safety. In principle in shouldn't matter, because whoever supplies the function pointer and user data pointer shouldn't have a great deal of difficulty ensuring that they match. In practice of course people find ways to write bugs, and ways to blame you because their compiler didn't tell them about the bugs ;-)

Answer (score 15):

The best that you can do is use `std::function` or `boost::function` as argument, together with `std::bind` or `boost::bind` to, well, bind the arguments with the function:

```
void foo() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
void bar( int x ) { std::cout << "bar(" << x << ")" << std::endl; }
struct test {
   void foo() { std::cout << "test::foo" << std::endl; }
};
void call( int times, boost::function< void() > f )
{
   for ( int i = 0; i < times; ++i )
      f();
}
int main() {
   call( 1, &foo );                   // no need to bind any argument
   call( 2, boost::bind( &bar, 5 ) );
   test t;
   call( 1, boost::bind( &test::foo, &t ) ); // note the &t
}
```

Note that there is something inherently wrong with passing a fully generic function pointer: how do you use it? How would the body of the calling function look like to be able to pass an undefined number of arguments of unknown types? That is what the `bind` templates resolve, they create a class functor that stores the function pointer (concrete function pointer) together with copies of the arguments to use when calling (note the `&t` in the example so that the pointer and not the object is copied). The result of the `bind` is a functor that can be called through a known interface, in this case it can be bound inside a `function< void() >` and called with no arguments.

Comment: will call then only take void functions?

Comment: @Ninja Yes of course. As the caller, if you don't even know what the return type is, how can you use the function? You can use `boost::function<void *>` and cast the return type to what you want. If you want modern C++ alternative, you can use `boost::function<boost::any>` to play with some type erasure.

Answer (score 2):

It's just an example how you could pass function pointer to another function, and then call it:

```
void AddTimer(float time, int repeats, void (*func)(int), int params)
{
    //call the func
    func(params);
}

void myfunction(int param)
{
   //...
}

AddTimer(1000.0, 10, myfunction, 10);
```

Similarly, you can write your code if your function takes different type or/and numbers of parameters!

Comment: +1, after rereading the question again, I am not too sure that the number and types of arguments are an unknown, and if these are known this is a simpler better solution than mine.

Comment: This is not what I asked actually. It looks like David's answer is of more use.

Answer (score 1):

If there's really no rules about the function pointer at all, just use void*.

Comment: `void(*)(void)` is better "generic" function pointer type than `void*` because if you do cast a value of type `void(*)(void)` back to the the correct function pointer type it is guaranteed that the original function pointer value will be preserved. This is not guaranteed if you cast a function pointer value to `void*` and back.

Comment: @DanielTrebbien: 5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast] / 6.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, things get really simple - you get everything you need to implement your timers.

The most concise way of passing bound function calls is by passing a functor generated using lambda syntax, e.g.: `[]{ std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl; }`. An object thus generated has a type known only to the compiler, but the type is convertible to `std::function<void()>`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <list>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>
class Timers {
public:
   using clock = Clock;
   using duration = typename clock::duration;
   using time_point = typename clock::time_point;
private:
   struct Timer {
      duration const period;
      std::function<void()> const call;
      int repeats;
      time_point next;
      Timer(duration $period, int $repeats, std::function<void()> && $call) :
         period($period), call(std::move($call)), repeats($repeats) {}
   };
   std::list<Timer> m_timers;
public:
   Timers() {}
   Timers(const Timers &) = delete;
   Timers & operator=(const Timers &) = delete;
   template <typename C> void add(std::chrono::milliseconds period,
                                  int repeats, C && callable)
   {
      if (repeats) m_timers.push_back(Timer(period, repeats, callable));
   }
   enum class Missed { Skip, Emit };
   void run(Missed missed = Missed::Emit) {
      for (auto & timer : m_timers) timer.next = clock::now() + timer.period;
      while (! m_timers.empty()) {
         auto next = time_point::max();
         auto ti = std::begin(m_timers);
         while (ti != std::end(m_timers)) {
            while (ti->next <= clock::now()) {
               ti->call();
               if (--ti->repeats <= 0) {
                  ti = m_timers.erase(ti);
                  continue;
               }
               do {
                  ti->next += ti->period;
               } while (missed == Missed::Skip && ti->next <= clock::now());
            }
            next = std::min(next, ti->next);
            ++ ti;
         }
         if (! m_timers.empty()) std::this_thread::sleep_until(next);
      }
   }
};

int main(void)
{
   Timers<> timers;
   using ms = std::chrono::milliseconds;
   timers.add(ms(1000), 2, []{ std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl; });
   timers.add(ms(100), 20, []{ std::cout << "*" << std::endl; });
   timers.run();
   std::cout << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```